# How to center align in tabular while I'm using vertical alignment such as "m", "b", or "p"?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tabularx, nicematrix

I want my widths of each cell to be specified just as in my code hence I'm using the vertical alignment `m{6mm}`. But now, how do I make all the values center aligned horizontally?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|m{1.5cm}||*{6}{m{6mm}|}}
\hline
$x_1$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
$y_1$ & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Results in:
[image: resulting table]

The goal is to have all the values to be at the `center` instead of `left aligned` as they are in the figure above.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Simply use `*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}{m{6mm}|}}`

Comment: I'm using this : `\begin{tabular}{|m{1.5cm}||*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}{m{6mm}|}}}`. But getting an error... **! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (m{6mm}|): `c' used.See the array package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}{m{6mm}|}}}**

Comment: The error initially says you have a parenthesis before  `m`, not a brace.  Some mistyping?

Comment: no mistyping, I think it's the error's way of highlighting a particular code like **...pream-token (`code`)**, because I used the code as it is in the previous comment. No unwanted parenthesis.

Comment: I first didn't notice:  you're ending with three  braces, whereas I have only two (I tested – it works normally). Also (unrelated), your table will look nicer if you interrupt the middle hline   so that it does not cross the double vertical rule (use hhline for that).

Comment: It finally worked! I kept getting an error when using two braces at the end, but turns out I added one extra brace just before 'm': `\begin{tabular}{|m{1.5cm}||*{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}**{**m{6mm}|}}`. So I removed that and it finally worked. Thank you

Comment: @ray_lv  welcome  -- please have a look at the answer below -- with lines and without lines and with slight color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{\columncolor{Gray}\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{|P{1.5cm}||*{6}{P{6mm}|}}
        \hline
        $x_1$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \hline
        $y_1$ & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabular}{P{1.5cm}*{6}{P{6mm}}}
    \toprule
    $x_1$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    
    $y_1$ & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}{Q{1.5cm}*{6}{P{6mm}}}
%   \toprule
    $x_1$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    
    $y_1$ & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
%   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}{P{1.5cm}*{6}{P{6mm}}}
    %   \toprule
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro!40}
    $x_1$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro!80}
    $y_1$ & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
    %   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

**EDIT -- with "m" type centering**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[table, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{\columncolor{Gray}\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{|P{1.5cm}||*{6}{P{6mm}|}}
        \hline
        $x_1$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \hline
        $y_1$ & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabular}{P{1.5cm}*{6}{P{6mm}}}
        \toprule
        $x_1$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        
        $y_1$ & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabular}{Q{1.5cm}*{6}{P{6mm}}}
        %   \toprule
        $x_1$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        
        $y_1$ & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
        %   \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabular}{P{1.5cm}*{6}{P{6mm}}}
        %   \toprule
        \rowcolor{Gainsboro!40}
        $x_1$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \rowcolor{Gainsboro!80}
        $y_1$ & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
        %   \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite related to my question, but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @ray_lv does the edit above to the answer satisfy the requirement  - -do let us know what is the shortcoming

Comment: Thank you for this: `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` . It is actually all that I needed, a few explanations regarding this macro would've been nice as well. The rest of the tabular aesthetics wasn't really part of the requirement that is asked in the question, it is good info but could cause confusion for someone who is interested in knowing how to center align the values.

Comment: @ray_lv  would you like to accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

A "nice" alternative to consider is the `nicematrix` package. `wc{<lenght>}` will center a column of that width.

By defining the Tikz nodes in the cells and their corners, the package offers many options  for customizing the tables, that will generally require several additional packages to achieve.

That way the code is much simpler and more compact.

It doesn't shine in this simple example, although the many examples in the manual are worth exploring and seeing.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|wc{1.5cm}||*{5}{wc{6mm}|}}
    \hline
    $x_1$ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    \hline
    $y_1$ & 10 & 20 & 30 & 40 & 50\\
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

(Only 6 columns need to be defined, not seven)